# Reload android activity without finishing it

Tags: android, reload, listactivity

I have one android activity which extends ListActivity. Every time list items is pressed the activity should change its state(new list adapter) and reload. To do that on item click I create new ArrayAdapter for the list and set it but instead of resetting the list of items new items are just appended to the older ones. How can I erase old list items and set new ones?

```
private void update() {
    if (flag == null) {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        list_items = new Vector();
        list_items.addAll(getNewListItems());
    }
    String[] items = new String[list_items.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<list_items.size(); i++) 
        items[i] = list_items.get(i).toString();
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_layout, R.id.label, items));
}
```

Comment: can't you just use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a **custom adapter**, then

You can just remove old items add your new items in your `String[] items`.

And just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to your adapter...

Then you don't have to call every time new adapter..

Comment: actually every time I create a new adapter, is that wrong? anyway, I tried to call notifyDataSetChanged() in the getView method of custom adapter and it didn't help - still old items are shown

Comment: Yes, everytime creation of new adapter is wrong, You have to call notifyDataSetChanged() after you create your new String[] items array(remove old) not in getView()..

Answer (score 0):

You should use notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter, then it will automatically reload all the items in the list.

You can find some more explanation from 17.00 and on in [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t=17m00s) Google IO video